# iphone php script

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm trying to send information from obj-c to my php script, but as I've learned, I can't send text that has _'s in it. I'm using the $_GET[''] function in PHP and it won't accept when I send it spaces.

For example, when I send the data to the url in objective-c I get this:

http://test.com/test/test.php?url=http://test.com/test/images/2011-07-22/542.jpg&username=iMac&comment=test comment with space

Any recommendations?
Cheers,

Filip,

Answer (score 1):

URL Encode it. That's what it's for.